# Use Graph API to get contacts from Outlook.com

Tags: powershell, api

I am trying to get a list of contacts via Graph API. In the portal.azure.com I went to App registrations and did a new registrations. I created secrets and added permission (picture below)
[image]

I am connecting to Graph API with this code

```
$Body = @{
    'tenant' = $TenantId
    'client_id' = $ClientId
    'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}


$Params = @{
    'Uri' = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    'Method' = 'Post'
    'Body' = $Body
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' -Headers $Headers
```

However I get the error message

*Invoke-RestMethod : {
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-09-04T17:54:13",
"request-id": "2113f712-f022-4ebc-8263-d26c469840d0"
}
}
}
At line:31 char:11

- $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/us ...
- ```
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand*

I assume when I get the user ID then I should be able to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ID/contacts API and I should be able to create/delete contacts. What am I missing or how can I achieve it please?

Comment: With any of `Directory.Read.All` and `User.Read.All` I had access to that call. Can you double check in the **API Permissions** page and confirm that the **Status** Column show **Granted for Org** message ? If not, you need to click the **Grant admin consent for Org** button in that page each time you change the permissions in order  for the new selected permission to take effect. If the application is registered in a different directory than the one it is used against, you will need to give an admin consent too (by building the special admin consent URL)

Comment: Thanks Sage, there is the issue. I have only standard Outlook.com account and I cannot consent the app. I changed the type to delegate access but struggling to get access token. Do you know by a chance how it can be accessed? Thanks

Comment: Ha, I missed the outlook part. I am used to work more with Azure org. Yeah, I think my answer below will sort your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I don't believe my answer is accurate as the "Me" endpoint won't work with the client_credential flow.

Original answer --

The **Users** endpoint is to query all users in your organization, which is different from contacts.

To get your outlook.com contacts, you need to have the following delegated permission in your application.

You will need to grant your application one of the following permissions

**permissions (delegated)**

- OrgContact.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.AccessAsUser.All

The endpoint you will be using is : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts`

You can experiment the different endpoints with [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). The website will also inform you of the required permissions for each calls (through the **Modify permissions** tab) and give you insights on all aspects of the call itself.

Comment: thanks that works well. The last question is if the token is permanent or if it expires? In case it expires is it somehow possible to get this access token with Powershell?

Comment: Are you sure you're able to get result from what I posted ? After trying again this morning, I can't anymore. I believe the client_credential flow is not the one to use with the "Me" endpoint. Unfortunately, I think my answer is falling through. If you remove the "best answer" flag, I'll remove my question to leave someone else provide a better answer.

Comment: For your comment, it is possible and it is done by adding the Offlline_Access scope, which in turn should provide you with the Refresh_Token in addition to the access_token. The refresh token purpose is to obtain a new access token without the need to re-authenticate.

Comment: your answer works the only disadvantage is that I need to copy the access token from graph explorer.

Comment: if you have time please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759554/graph-api-get-token. Maybe you can advice.