# Graph API get token

Tags: powershell, api

I am trying to get Graph API token on behal of the user. I am following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user and everything works well until the step 3 Get a Token. Here is the code I am using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$clientIDEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientid)
$redirectUriEncoded =  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf")
$scopeEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")
 
Function Get-AuthCode {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=440;Height=640}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=420;Height=600;Url=($url -f ($Scope)) }
 
    $DocComp  = {
        $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri        
        if ($Global:uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 
    $queryOutput = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($web.Url.Query)
    $output = @{}
    foreach($key in $queryOutput.Keys){
        $output["$key"] = $queryOutput[$key]
    }
 
    $output
}
 
 
# Get AuthCode
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirectUriEncoded&client_id=$clientID&scope=$scopeEncoded"

$authcode=(Get-AuthCode).values
 
Write-output "Received an authCode, $authCode"
 
$body = "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=$redirectUri&client_id=$clientId&code=$authCode&scope=$scopeEncoded"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token `
    -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
    -Body $body `
```

I get the authcode something like that

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                
code                           M.R3_BAY.f659093f-3327-c99b-e219-9b3c7f82fd95                                                                                                                                                                        
lc                             1051
```

and then when I try to get a token I get this error message

```
$body = "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=$redirectUri&client_id=$clientId&code=$authCode&scope=$scopeEncoded"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token `
    -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
    -Body $body `
Received an authCode, M.R3_BAY.c622845d-f126-9017-134f-e79f3a24c4d4 1051


*

Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 194d7f79-af2e-46e1-b287-c14c364b0200\r\nCorrelation ID: 1348166c-c93c-4cc6-8e57-0c2d32ab2b78\r\nTime
    stamp: 2020-09-05 23:53:19Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2020-09-05 23:53:19Z","trace_id":"194d7f79-af2e-46e1-b287-c14c364b0200","correlation_id":"1348166c-c93c-4cc6-8e57-0c2d32ab2b78","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/err
    or?code=9002313"}
    At line:47 char:18
    + ... nResponse = Invoke-RestMethod https://login.microsoftonline.com/commo ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

- 

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://engineerer.ch/2021/07/01/how-to-use-powershell-to-call-graph-api-endpoints/
I was using MSAL.PS. Might be possible to get an API token on behalf of a user as well. Maybe you need to dig into MSAL.NET as well: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet